# Tic-tac-toe on android studio

Tags: android

I want do a tic-tac-toe on android studio. So i do this:

```
public class MainActivity2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
char a;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    final Button button0=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
    final Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button button3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    final Button button4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    final Button button5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    final Button button6=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    final Button button7=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    final Button button8=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    final Button player1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    final Button player2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.player2);
    player1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a='X';

        }
    });
    player2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a='O';
        }
    });
    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button0.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button3.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button4.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button5.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button6.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button7.setText(a);
        }
    });
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button8.setText(a);
        }
    });
```

but when i open the app and click to the bottons to write there a x or a o the app say : the application is stopped abnormally. How can I fix it, please answer me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setText method accepts String variables
change type of your variable to String and use " instead of '

> public final void setText (CharSequence text)
>   Sets the string value of the TextView

Answer (score 0):

You used the same id player 2 twice for both players